# Parse push notifications occasionally stop arriving until device disconnects and reconnects to the internet

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications, push

I am using Parse Push REST API to send push notifications from my Java server to specific devices , filtering by device token.
Usually everything works well. But sometimes I notice an expected push notification has not reached the destination.
After a while, I started noticing that if I disconnect the device from the internet and then re-connect it, all the push notifications suddenly arrive at once.

To me it seems like some sort of bug with the `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` but I am just unsure what it may be.

This is what I am actually doing in the code:

```
public class MyParsePushBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

// Doing what I want

// Calling original onPushReceive
super.onPushReceive(context, intent);

}

}
```

This is the Parse installation initialization:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
// Initializing Parse for push notifications.
    Parse.initialize(this, Constants.APPLICATION_ID, Constants.CLIENT_KEY);
    if(getDeviceToken().equals("")) {
        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("MyChannel");
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {

                Intent i = new Intent(context, GetTokenIntentService.class);
                i.setAction(GetTokenIntentService.ACTION_GET_TOKEN);
                context.startService(i);

            }
        });
    }
```

If necessary, I will post the contents of `GetTokenIntentService`.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the edit @rici.
I would also appreciate if someone answers because I am really lost on this one.

Comment: This still reproduces...anyone please??